# Modify a field anytime another field is modified

Tags: c#, field

Well, the title says it, but I'll be more specific to my situation and explain my problem.
I have the following classes:

```
class Attribute{
    private int score;
    private int tempScore;
    private int misc;

    // here I have getters and setters
    // A method
    public int Modifier(){
        return (score+tempScore-10)/2;
    }
}
```

and

```
class SavingThrow{
    private int base;
    private int resistance;
    private int bonus;
    private int misc;

    //Getters and setters here
    //A method
    public int Total(){
        return base + resistance + bonus + misc;
    }
}
```

Let us say that now I have a Player A with an Attribute wisdom and a SavingThrow will. Whenever the first is modified, e.g.:

```
A.Wisdom.Score = 12;
```

then, the second must be modified as a consequence. In this example I should make:

```
A.Will.Bonus = A.Wisdom.Modifier();
```

*Any idea on how to achieve this*?

I thought of the following solution but it doesn't satisfy me for the reason I'm going to explain.
I won't define getters, so external access to Wisdom can be done only through a pre-defined public method, say SetWisdom(int score), and in that method I update Will. Though, the problem with this is, that if I have to modify tempScore or misc instead, I have to make another method to do it. **It seems pretty unefficient**, expecially if I add more fields to Attribute class.
Else, I could use a SetWisdom (Attribute wisdom) method which replaces the whole attribute with a new object, in which I have to copy ALL the unmodified fields and replace the one I need. **This seems a bit clumsy and inelegant**.
Which solution would you choose and, more importantly, *do you have better ideas on how to handle this*?

Comment: `base` is a keyword in C#, you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: I think [you're looking for `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Your fields will have to change to properties, and while you're at it, you may as well change your methods `Total` and `Modifier` to read-only properties, to be consistent with standard .NET usage.

Comment: @UnholyShep: yeah, I've just noticed. I'm pretty new to C#, so I didn't know it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: thanks, I'll check that! :) I had made read-only properties before, but then I had to change them anytime one field was changed, that's why I changed it into a method returning the expression. But maybe there is a more intelligent workaround than my solution, to keep using properties.

Comment: @Harnak This is a read-only property: `public int Total { get { return base + resistance + bonus + misc; } }`

Comment: @EdPlunkett: omg, that was so obvious, but I didn't think of it. I'm not used to using getters and setters. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is to not make copies of the value at all, then you don't have to keep track where you copied it to to update it.

```
class SavingThrow{
    private int base;
    private int resistance;
    private Attribute attribute;
    private int misc;

    //Getters and setters here
    //A method
    public int Total(){
        return base + resistance + attribute.Modifier + misc;
    }
}
```

Your class could be used like this, if you set the attribute in the constructor:

```
Attribute wisdom = new Attribute(16);
SavingThrow will = new SavingThrow(wisdom);

Console.WriteLine(will.Total());

wisdom.Add(2);

Console.WriteLine(will.Total());
```

The total score should have increased (assuming adding two to wisdom increases the modifier) because the saving throw class never held a *copy*, but references wisdom directly.

Comment: Very clear and nice solution. I'll try this! Many thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem but with an integer. Player has a `size` field and ArmorClass has a `size` field. Though, I'm forced to copy it now because that's not an object but a primitive (also I cannot leave the field only in ArmorClass because I need it in Player for other classes too). Should I use a pointer? Though it is `unsafe` territory, so I'm not sure that's the right solution. Or should I just pack it in a class and use that?

Comment: @Harnak Does the size of the armor change with the player? Or the other way round? You could simply let the player by a property of the armor called "wearer" or the armor be a property of the player called "WornArmor" if they need to be connected.

Comment: The ArmorClass is just a set of three numbers actually which depend on the Player's size, armor and other things (except for a possible penalty which may depend not on the Player). So the size in there is exactly the same value as the one in Player. So, I have an ArmorClass field in the Player to 'connect' them, though I don't know how to pick the size anytime the player's size is modified. Wouldn't a property yield the same problem? Or if I use a property in Player, I could put `return ArmorClass( // the numbers it depens on) //constructor` in its getter. Maybe you mean this?

Comment: I meant `return new ArmorClass(//numbers it depends on) // constructor` in the previous comment.